# MongoDB: Dynamically generated field value

Tags: mongodb

Suppose that I have a database with student information:

```
{'student_name' : 'Alen', 'subjects' : {'cse101' : 4, 'cse102' : 3, 'cse201' : 4}}
```

Suppose I need to store the aggregate information of the student as well. I can add the field `'aggregate' : 3.67` to the record. But the aggregate changes when another subject is added to the `subjects` list. Is there a way I can write a "dynamic field" which could calculate the aggregate whenever requested? Something like `student['aggregate']` which is not persistent but available when needed?

P.S: Aggregate is just a simple example. I am dealing with something more complex involving various other fields of the element.

Comment: your above json is wrong, itshould be `{'cse101;: 4, 'cse102': 3, 'cse201': 4}`.
Notice the braces `{` instead of brackets `[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no dynamic or calculated fields in MongoDB at the moment (although there are [some tickets](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2549) in the jira).

But you can always implement this functionality in the app code.

Comment: Yes, I do it in the app code now. I don't want to do something redundant which has already provided by mongodb. Thanks!